# RTMP stream player?

Tags: ios, native, rtmp, beatsmusic

would like to integrate native iOS app with Beats Music API. Can anyone suggest a good (open source) RTMP stream player? Will Apple reject my app if I do anything like that? Beats Music does not have the intention to support http streaming anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of iOS internals but I would suggest you have a look at [VLCKit](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit%20VLCKIt). We are using VLC as the audio backend for a Desktop Player. Beats Music rmtp:// streams run nicely with the latest nightly builds of VLC.